# Можно ли вставить текст перед переменной в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Можно ли вставить текст перед переменной в mysql?

```
@serial := 1    
INSERT INTO test (some) VALUES (@serial+' Текст');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для конкатенации (объединения) строк в MySQL используется функция `concat()`:

```
INSERT INTO test (some) VALUES (concat(@serial,' Текст'));
```